# Where are Ubuntu packages that I can't find by name (OpenJDK, Ruby, etc.)?

Tags: ubuntu, repository, apt-get

Just installed Ubuntu 9.0.4. When using `apt-get`, I found I could not get packages like OpenJDK, Ruby etc.

Do I need to add some additional repository?

Comment: `apt-cache search --names-only ruby`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be that the packages are not available under the name you expect them to be. Or you haven't enabled [all repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) necessary. In any case, enable the "Universe" repository, as it contains most third-party tools.

- OpenJDK is `openjdk-7-jre`, as mentioned on [its website](http://openjdk.java.net/install/).
- Ruby is in a few packages, but installing either `ruby`, `ruby-full` or `ruby1.9.1` should do according to the [Ruby website](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) and the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails). Note that you would be better off using [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) if you want to do serious work with Ruby and Gems. The packaged version of Ruby in Ubuntu might not always be the latest, and switching between versions is rather complicated without RVM.
- For any other package, just look at the official website, if there is one. Ubuntu is so popular that it's hard *not*  to find the appropriate package name. If you had to incldue additional non-Ubuntu repositories, you'd read about that in the installation documentation anyway.

Comment: The universe repository is enabled, hoevere I found the repository cannot be connected. My network is OK

Comment: Ah it might be because you're using 9.04 and there aren't any official repositories for it anymore. Your release is EOL (End of Line); therefore you should maybe upgrade to a newer one, e.g. 10.04, which is a long-term supported release.